# Deliver variables to a user control nested in a listview

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, webusercontrol

I have a problem, I have a listview with a web user control in it like this

```
    <asp:ListView ID="TestView" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%# Eval("ExampleData")%>
            <uc1:TestControl runat="server" id="TestControl" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

The problem I'm trying to solve is to send the variable in `ExampleData` to the control on the same row.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a public property on the control and pass it as argument:

```
<uc1:TestControl runat="server" id="TestControl" Example='<%# Eval("ExampleData")%>'/>
```

Inside your user control write this:

```
Public string Example { get; set;}
```